# Update a status field comparing dates after an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is the schema and my model for Visit (visit's status can be: *Confirmed, Current, Expired and To be approved*)

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "visits", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.date     "start"
    t.date     "end"
    t.integer  "idVisit"
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.integer  "visitor_id"
    t.string   "status",      default: "Confirmed"
  end
```

**Visit.rb**

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to          :employee
    belongs_to          :visitor
    default_scope   ->  { order(:created_at) }

    validates   :start,           presence: true,     uniqueness: {scope: [:end, :visitor_id]}
    validates   :end,             presence: true
    validates   :visitor_id,      presence: true
    validates   :employee_id,     presence: true
    validate    :valid_date_range_required

    def valid_date_range_required
        if (start && end) && (end < start)
            errors.add(:end, "must be after start")
        end
    end
end
```

Now my problem is that I need to compare for each visit, after each time I do show action in employees_controller.rb, the start and end date to Date.today (except for To be approved status); according to it I will change the status of visits in the database.

Here is what I did but probably there will be some mistakes since for now an error occurs at least, so I hope you could help me to fix it.

In **Visit.rb** I created this:

```
def check_visit_status(visit)

        if visit.status != 'To be confirmed'
            if visit.start <= Date.today && visit.end >= Date.today
               visit.status = 'Current'
            end

            if visit.end < Date.today
                visit.status = 'Expired'
            end
        end  
    end
```

Now in **employees_controller.rb** I have (I won't post it all):

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    after_action :update_status,  only: :show

    def show

        if logged_in?
            @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
            @indirizzimac = current_employee.indirizzimacs.new
            @visitor = current_employee.visitors.new
            @visit = current_employee.visits.new
            @visits = current_employee.visits.all
            if params[:act]=='myData'
                render 'myData'
            elsif params[:act]=='myNetwork'
                render 'myNetwork'
            elsif params[:act]=='temporaryUsers'
                render 'temporaryUsers'
            elsif params[:act]=='guestsVisits'
                render 'guestsVisits'
            elsif params[:act]=='myAccount'
                render 'myAccount'
            else
                render 'show'
            end
        else
            render 'static_pages/errorPage'
        end
    end

    def update_status
        if @visits.any?
           @visits.each do |visit|
              check_visit_status(visit)
           end
        end
     end
end
```

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Please post what error you get.  At first look it appears your error is that you are not saving the changes you are making to `@visits` in update_status.  Modifying an instance variable alone won't change its values in your database, you need to call something like `@visits.save` after

Comment: The error is: undefined method `check_visit_status' for #<EmployeesController:0x007fcbaf923fb0>

Answer (score 1):

I really have to thank eeeeeean for his immense help.

I figured out my problem so I want to post here my solution in order to help someone looking for the same thing I was asking for.

**employees_controller.rb**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    after_action :update_status,  only: :show

    def show
    [...]
    end

    def update_status
        if @visits.any?
           @visits.each do |visit|
              visit.check_visit_status
           end
        end
     end
end
```

**Visit.rb**

```
def check_visit_status
        if self.status != 'To be confirmed'
            if self.start <= Date.today && self.end >= Date.today
               self.update_attribute :status, 'Current'

            end

            if self.end < Date.today
                self.update_attribute :status, 'Expired'

            end
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `check_visit_status` on an instance of Visit, but right now it's being called on `self`, which in this scope refers to the employees controller. Try this:

**visit.rb**

```
def check_visit_status
  if self.status != 'To be confirmed'
    if self.start <= Date.today && end >= Date.today
      self.status = 'Current'
     end
    if self.end < Date.today
      self.status = 'Expired'
    end
  end  
end
```

Then call it like this:

**employees_controller.rb**

```
@visits.each do |visit|
  visit.check_visit_status
end
```

That should get you out of that particular error.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now I don't get this error anymore. Unfortunately visits' status on database have not been changed. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you used the byebug gem? You could throw that on the end of your check_visit_status method to make sure all of your logic for that method checks out.

Comment: I put byebug before if @.visits.any? and writing _display @.visits_ it's not empty. Writing next, the => goes to @visits.each do |visit| and after another next I see: 
**Visit Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "visits".* FROM "visits" WHERE "visits"."employee_id" = ?  ORDER BY "visits"."created_at" ASC  [["employee_id", 1]]
Next went up a frame because previous frame finished**

So it goes to a callback function and @.visits = nil. I don't really understand what's happening. (I put @. so that the system could let me post)

Comment: Put byebug in your check_visit_status method, not in your controller. byebug will interrupt the flow of your program and give you a console with all variables that are available to the scope where you put byebug. If you expect that method to process a few visit objects (it looks like you do), you can tell byebug to 'continue' (instead of 'next') and the flow of the program will be resumed until it loops to byebug again. You're going to have to experiment with it on your own, but it will probably be a helpful tool for you here. Good luck.

Comment: First of all, thank you because you're helping me a lot. I did what you said and I saw that each visit's status is changed by my method if it's necessary. After the last visit the application goes to [link](https://gyazo.com/ce9c2fda55effc1bb6b770f35d614c12) but I don't understand why. I have another question too: through my method I changed visits' status, but I think I'm not updating their status in the database; how could I do?

Comment: Thank you a lot again, I figure it out.